# how to know what view is clicked to open context menu?

Tags: android, contextmenu

i have two button where i register a context menu

```
but1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageViewX);
but2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageViewY);      
registerForContextMenu(but);
registerForContextMenu(but2);
```

I have a problem in onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) how to know if user click but1 or but2 ?
with id=item.getItemId(); i have the id of item selected, but i want to know what button is clicked in onContextItemSelected method.

Answer (score 0):

When you create contextitem create unique ids for each of the two Imagebuttons

```
 public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View view, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
 {
   if(view.getId() == R.id.imageViewX)
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+1, Menu.NONE, "imageViewX");
   else     
      menu.add(Menu.NONE, Menu.FIRST+10, Menu.NONE, "imageViewY");

   super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, view, menuInfo);
 }
```

And in

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == (Menu.FIRST+1)) {
       //do something
    }else if(item.getItemId() == (Menu.FIRST+10)){
       //do something else
    }

}
```